# Hive import only certain file types from hdfs

Tags: hive, hdfs, hiveql, hive-serde, hiveddl

I’m creating a external table using Serde

> org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerde

Hdfs folder location has multiple file formats and I would like to import only **json** files types . I tried to use

```
**SERDEPROPERTIES (“input.regex” = “*.json”)**
```

But does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Hive has virtual column named INPUT__FILE__NAME and you can filter it in the where clause.

```
select * from --do everything else on this level
(select * from your_table --do filtering in the subquery wrapper
where INPUT__FILE__NAME rlike '\\.json$' --ends with .json
)s
```

I'm not sure it will efficiently work because these related Jiras unfortunately are not implemented yet: [Add file pruning into Hive](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1662)  and [Selectively include EXTERNAL TABLE source files via REGEX](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-951)

If this solution will work slow because mappers will read files, you may need to copy files required to the separate folder and build a table on top of it.

Have found one more solution which you can possibly use: [SymlinkTextInputFormat](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1272)

Create some new location with a file containing a list of all files required and build a table on top of this location.

For example, the location of the table is `"/user/hive/mytable"`.
There is a file called "/user/hive/mytable/myfile.txt".
Inside the file, there are 2 lines, `"/user/myname/textfile1.txt"` and `"/user/myname/textfile2.txt"`

We can do:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (...) STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat' LOCATION '/user/hive/mytable';
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

which will return the content of the 2 files: "/user/myname/textfile1.txt" and "/user/myname/textfile2.txt"